# Make valgrind stop immediately after first error

Tags: debugging, valgrind

my program processes large errors and during development in produces large amount of output on the console. It suffers from memory corruption and I try to use valgrind to locate the error.

Unfortunately, i can't find the error messages among the output lines, and they flushing by too fast to cancel execution when they pop up. They have to be there in order to locate the error ( which element does cause the error and so on ). Redirecting then within my program doesn't work, just like piping the output does only redirect the program output, not the valgrind output.

Can you give me a hint how to solve this.

Comment: It is unfortunate that the answer which directly answers the question – for recent valgrind versions – https://stackoverflow.com/a/50289059/ – isn't the accepted answer and doesn't come first in the list (except when you use the non-default sorts of Trending or Date modified). The other answers are not direct answers to the question–largely because they date back to the time when `--exit-on-first-error=` didn't yet exist, and hence there wasn't really a direct answer back then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask `valgrind` to save its output into file:

```
valgrind --log-file=<filename>
```

where `<filename>` is the file name for output. Later you can view this file with `less` or text editor.

Comment: This "disconnects" VG output from program output, which OP claimed is needed to know what data the program was processing at the time of VG error.

Answer (score 31):

In addition to redirecting both program and Valgrind output to a file (as already suggested), you can use `--db-attach=yes` flag, which will cause your program to stop in the debugger right at the error.

This has the advantage that in addition to looking at the log your program produced, you can also look at other program state (that you are not logging).

Comment: Super useful flag -- never knew about this in my years of using gdb. Thanks!

Comment: I see they removed this option in the latest valgrind.  It was so incredibly useful and I have a hard time debugging without it, are you aware of an alternative?

Comment: Yes, use `--vgdb-error=0` instead, and follow the instructions.

Comment: Actually, --vgdb-error=1 is closer.  (=0 will allow you to set breakpoints before, =1 stops at the error)

Answer (score 16):

If you want it to stop in the console (not in a file), here is a way to do it :

Use the parameter : `--gen-suppressions=yes`

When you debug it will stops like this :

```
==949== Thread 2:
==949== Invalid read of size 4
==949==    at 0x7B62DC0: wcslen (wcslen.S:24)
==949==    by 0x7B62D7D: wcsdup (wcsdup.c:29)
==949==    by 0x52D0476: de_strdup(wchar_t*) (de_string.cpp:1442)
==949==    by 0x437629: void de_format<>(c_de_string&, wchar_t*) (de_string.h:368)
==949==    by 0x45F4FB: int db_select_group<>(s_db*, s_pqexec_param*, wchar_t*, wchar_t*, wchar_t*, wchar_t*, int, wchar_t*) (in /corto/goinfre/code2/cortod.repo/bin/x64/Debug/cortod)
==949==    by 0x45EA96: check_oldgeom(c_cartod*) (cartod_funcs.cpp:114)
==949==    by 0x45EBF8: armserv_update_geom(c_cartod*) (cartod_funcs.cpp:149)
==949==    by 0x455EF9: c_cortosrv_thread::on_timeout() (cartod.cpp:163)
==949==    by 0x52FE500: c_de_thread::loop() (de_thread.cpp:35)
==949==    by 0x52FEE97: thread_loop(void*) (de_thread_priv_linux.cpp:85)
==949==    by 0x506E181: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==949==    by 0x7BBA47C: clone (clone.S:111)
==949==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==949== 
==949== 
==949== ---- Print suppression ? --- [Return/N/n/Y/y/C/c] ----
```

Then you can go to the next one continue all etc.

The normal purpose of this parameter is to remove the false positives, by printing suppression that you can add in a file and pass it to valgrind using the parameter : `--suppressions=<filename>`

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 12):

Valgrind 3.14.0 has `--exit-on-first-error` option:

```
ERROR-RELATED OPTIONS         top

       These options are used by all tools that can report errors, e.g.
       Memcheck, but not Cachegrind.

   ...

   --exit-on-first-error=<yes|no> [default: no]
       If this option is enabled, Valgrind exits on the first error. A
       nonzero exit value must be defined using --error-exitcode option.
       Useful if you are running regression tests or have some other
       automated test machinery.
```

This option must be used together with `--error-exitcode` option, so possible Valgrind invocation can be:

```
valgrind --exit-on-first-error=yes --error-exitcode=1 ...
```

Comment: option not present on valgrind 1:3.13.0-2.1 amd64 on debian testing

Comment: For future reference: the first version that supports this is  3.14 according to [the changelog](http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.news.html)

Comment: I was frustrated that --exit-on-first-error=yes is rejected by valgrind, but it turns out you also have to add "--error-exitcode=1", at least with valgrind 3.15.0 on debian.

Comment: Compile latest valgrind is not hard.

Answer (score 3):

Valgrind outputs to stderr (fd 2) by default. You can capture stderr by redirecting file desctiptor 2:

```
# Output to log file.
valgrind [options] > valgrind.log 2>&1

# View output interactively.
valgrind [options] 2>&1 | less
```

Or you could use the `--log-fd` option to change where output is sent:

```
valgrind [options] --log-fd=1 > valgrind.log
valgrind [options] --log-fd=1 | less
```