# Is there a way to stop Valgrind on the first error it finds?

Tags: debugging, valgrind, terminate

If errors are found in valgrind's output, I want to generate the output using the debug version of the program. However, valgrinding thousands of runs in debug is way too time-intensive.

So what I would like to do is run in release mode, and if an error is found abort the run and complete the testing in debug.

Short of monitoring the output and killing the process manually, is there a better solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make valgrind stop immediately after first error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983746/make-valgrind-stop-immediately-after-first-error)

Comment: There is a new option in valgrind 3.13 https://stackoverflow.com/a/50289059/721644

Answer (score 2):

You can use `--db-attach=yes` and `--db-command=` to execute specific command you want to stop your Valgrind execution. But for normal debug process, `--db-command` invokes `gdb` with child process. So you cannot stop the execution by killing the process using `--db-command=kill -9 %p`, because it just kills the child process, not the Valgrind itself.

If you are using Linux and has `/proc` file system support, you can get the parent process number in the 4th column in `/proc/PID/stat`. Such that you have the chance to kill the parent process to stop Valgrind.

For example,

`valgrind --db-attach=yes --db-command="cat /proc/%p/stat | cut -d' ' -f4 | xargs kill -9" ./a.out`

When the first error appears, you will be asked

`---- Attach to debugger ? --- [Return/N/n/Y/y/C/c] ----`

And when you press `Y`, it will try to invoke debug command. So in this case, it will get the parent process ID, which is valgrind, and send KILL signal to the process. Therefore, Valgrind shall be immediately stopped.

Comment: `--db-attach` is obsolete, use `--vgdb=yes` and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 2):

> So what I would like to do is run in release mode, and if an error is found abort the run and complete the testing in debug.

Assuming you have two executables: `a.out` and `a.out-g`, and you want to run them with different sets of arguments, this should work in `bash`:

```
# Arguments to try
args=(
  "-foo"
  "-foo -bar"
  "-bar -baz"
  ...
)
for a in "${args[@]}"; do
   if valgrind -q --error-exitcode=1 \
       --db-attach=yes --db-command="kill -9 %p" ./a.out $a; then
     echo PASS: ./a.out $a
   else
     echo FAIL: ./a.out $a
     valgrind ./a.out-g $a
   fi 
done
```

Answer (score 2):

`--db-attach=yes` argument does not exist anymore.

Current usage is mediated via `vgdb` binary:

1. start program with valgrind:

`valgrind --vgdb=yes --vgdb-error=0 my_prog`

It displays what to do in next step:

```
==2466== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2466== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2466== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2466== Command: ./my_prog
==2466== 
==2466== (action at startup) vgdb me ... 
==2466== 
==2466== TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB: start GDB like this
==2466==   /path/to/gdb ./my_prog
==2466== and then give GDB the following command
==2466==   target remote | /usr/bin/vgdb --pid=2466
```

2. so you start another terminal and run gdb with your binary

`gdb ~/Sources/my_prog`

3. and attach to the stopped process 2466:

`(gdb) target remote | /usr/bin/vgdb --pid=2604`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
valgrind --gen-suppressions=no|yes|all
```

as it currently stands - its for suppressions but I am sure that it'll match your needs.