# Exit valgrind on first error

Tags: valgrind

I want valgrind to stop on the first error it finds and **exit**.

Please do not suggest

- `--vgdb-error=1`: It does not exit valgrind. You have to connect gdb and kill from there.
- `--db-attach`: Deprecated and removed in a recent release
- `--log-file=<filename>`: It does not stop valgrind.

My intention is to save my time and get my shell back as soon as the first error is printed. The first error is all I care about.

Comment: @PaulRooney Edited to rule out the duplicate. I want a solution with minimal number of steps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make valgrind stop immediately after first error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983746/make-valgrind-stop-immediately-after-first-error)

Comment: There is a new option in vagrind 3.13 https://stackoverflow.com/a/50289059/721644

Answer (score 1):

`--gen-suppressions=yes` will pause on each error and ask you if you wish to continue.

In addition to that, you can specify `--input-fd=<file descriptor>` to provide an alternative to `stdin` (standard input) at the moment of interacting with the suppression menu.